# How do I not grab all api data at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Hey guys i've managed to get my star wars api data from json to display on my app. I got the name object by setting state to people.name however when I set it as just 'people' it renders everything including data I don't want to use.

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
  jedi: [],
   searchfield: ''
}
    }

        componentDidMount(){
         fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
      .then(response => { return response.json()})
       .then(people => this.setState({jedi: JSON.stringify(people)}))
        }

    render(){
      return (
           <div className = 'charcards'>
             <div>
             <img className= 'pic' alt = 'Luke Skywalker' src = {luke} />
                </div>
                <hr/>
         <h2  className = "name1"> Name: {this.state.jedi.name}</h2>
         <h2 className = 'height'> {this.state.jedi.height}</h2>
          </div>
      );
    }

  }
```

I seem to be able to get name if I change   `.then(people => this.setState({jedi: JSON.stringify(people)}))` into

```
.then(people => this.setState({jedi: JSON.stringify(people.name)}))
```

but then i'm not able to call the rest of my data such as height, mass etc. When I just call people, it calls a whole plethora of unnecessary data. Should I loop through the api and pick out just the data I want, how would I approach that however as i tried looping through it but couldn't render the data. Calling `this.state.jedi.name` or `this.state.jedi.height` doesn't work as it just calls everything

Comment: what's wrong with getting all the data?

Comment: Can you post a sandboxed example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fetch partial data until the API supports so. Insted you can always use only what you want. Find the source useful.....

```
    class Card extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
      jediBio: {},
       searchfield: ''
    }
        }

            componentDidMount(){
             fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
          .then(response => { return response.json()})
           .then(people => this.setState({jediBio: people}))
            }

        render(){
//Define luke here else will throw luke as undefined
Let luke = "http://media.comicbook.com/2017/03/star-wars-luke-skywalker-239385.png";
          return (
               <div className = 'charcards'>
                 <div>
                 <img className= 'pic' alt = 'Luke Skywalker' src = {luke} />
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
             <h2  className = "name1"> Name: {this.state.jediBio.name}</h2>
             <h2 className = 'height'> {this.state.jediBio.height}</h2>
              </div>
          );
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in this line:

`.then(people => this.setState({jedi: JSON.stringify(people)})`

You are invoking `JSON.stringify()` on your response object, which serializes it into a string. If you want to able to access properties of the response JSON, you can remove it to get:

`.then(people => this.setState({jedi: people})`

Also it looks like your `this.state.jedi` state is an array, so make sure to iterate over each `this.state.jedi` when retrieving the `name` and `height` properties vs. doing `this.state.jedi.<name | height>`.

Comment: Would I set it like

  <h2  className = "name1"> Name: {this.state.jedi.map(jedi => {
           return  {jedi.name}   })}</h2>?

Comment: Ah wait I got it thnx